# Launch app from within blackberry calendar

Tags: blackberry

We create calendar entries in the blackberry calendar via our applicatin.

Our client wanted to know whether it is possible to launch our applicatin from within the blackberry calendar when they acces entries created by us.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can.  Refer to the BlackBerry API and see ApplicationMenuItem and ApplicationMenuItemRepository.  Within the run method of ApplicationMenuItem you can either launch your application or post a GlobalEvent which your application can subscribe to.

When your application created the calendar entry you could/should have got a UUID for the entry in return. You could set the UUID of the calendar entry selected as an argument in the Global Event and check in your application whether it was an entry your application created.