# How can I open the app from the url of calendar like Blackberry travel?

Tags: events, blackberry

I´m developing an app like Blackberry Travel. In Blackberry Travel, when add a flight, it adds in the calendar. In this event has 'Notes', where appears a url to load the app and see the flight.

I need doing the same, but only the load the app behavior. So, I have two question:

- How can I open the app from the url? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568503/how-to-launch-an-application-from-the-browser-in-blackberry) but, when I use the sample HttpFilterDemo, when I click in the url www.rim.com that I typed in an event of the calendar, never execute setRequestProperty method.
- How can I show 'Open with Blackberry' when I click in the url ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch app from within blackberry calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124490/launch-app-from-within-blackberry-calendar)

Comment: Also might help: [Create a Content Handler App](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Create_BB_app_plays_media_from_a_user_734821_11.jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s done!

A perfect example in [blackberry developer documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ui_active_text_fields_1988859_11.html)